# Facebook Fan Box on Fan Page

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to add a fan box widget to a application tab on a facebook fan page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I've just done it !

Here is the recipe:

1. add an fb iframe to your app page by setting the src to an url on the same domain you are running your app. Be sure to give the absolute path.
2. your url should point to a xfbml page (read carefully this page http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/XFBML).
3. In this page, put inside the body: " name="" stream="0" connections="0" width="250" height="120">

And voila ! It works for me. Now, I have to figure out how to detect when the user clicks on the button.

Comment: Didier, you can't detect the click on fan box though you can achieve the same using like-box widget, it fires edge.create event to track the click event.